# Unnest only one column of nested data frames

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

Given a nested data frame like for example

```r
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
m <- mtcars %>% nest_by(cyl)
```

I want to extract one of the columns in the nested data frames to the top level, creating
more rows but not as many as if I would use `m %>% unnest(data)`

What works for me and gives me the output I want is

```r
m %>% rowwise(-data) %>% summarise(nest_by(data, gear), .groups = "drop")
```

However, I feel as if I chose a convoluted road to my target because what I want to achieve is partial *un*-nesting, and I do it by first making an *additional* nesting that is then unnested again using the `summary(<tibble>)` semantics.

I tried `m %>% hoist(data, "cyl")` but this only got me an additional list column.

Is there a canonical function in dplyr that conveys the intention "partial unnesting" better than my solution?

Comment: Do you just want `mtcars %>% nest_by(cyl, gear)`?

Comment: @Axeman The question starts with `m`, which is already nested. I want to go the opposite way, unnest, but not everything

Answer (score 2):

You don't need `rowwise`, because `nest_by()` already gives a rowwise grouped tibble. Since dplyr 1.1.0, `summarise` should be replaced with `reframe` which is more appropriate for those situations where multiple rows are returned by group:

```r
m %>% reframe(nest_by(data, gear))

# # A tibble: 8 × 3
#     cyl  gear               data
#   <dbl> <dbl> <list<tibble[,9]>>
# 1     4     3            [1 × 9]
# 2     4     4            [8 × 9]
# 3     4     5            [2 × 9]
# 4     6     3            [2 × 9]
# 5     6     4            [4 × 9]
# 6     6     5            [1 × 9]
# 7     8     3           [12 × 9]
# 8     8     5            [2 × 9]
```